# PayPal Sandbox token

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Postman to get my PayPal Sandbox Token, an i keep getting the following respond: 404 Not Found
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client Authentication failed"
}
I am following the docs with the following url https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/ 
I also tried using cURL with the following command: by using my client_id and secret and i get the same result

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is something wrong with the client id, secret values. Please double check the client id and secret values. You will need to use sandbox credentials against sandbox end point for getting the access token. I tried the same curl request and its working without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, i am using paypal android sdk with my Android App, and i am using the same sandbox client id and the payment are successfully done, i checked my sandbox credentials multiple times but with no success

Comment: can you please check the environment for finding whether it is set to sandbox/Live environment.

Comment: I will recheck, please allow me to ask you one more question, i am confused about payments verification. after payment is successfully done in my app, i am storing the payment id and payment state to mysql data base, as requested by PayPal, so that i can later verify the payments. My question is, what is the next step? Can i use Postman or cURL to manually verify the payments using payment id, or this should be dong using PayPal php sdk? Thanks and sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: No worries. You can run get payment details API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get whenever you want to list the payment details using PAY ID. This feature is available in PayPal PHP SDK as well.

Comment: So the payment will not be completed until i do this Get Request and save the payment details somewhere?

Comment: In order to complete the payment, you will need to call execute payment. If you want to get the payment details then call get payment details API with PAY Id then you will get payment details. Getting payment details and execute payment both are different API calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and patience I appreciated, wish you the best